# How to exclude pending migrations on Django 3.1

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating my first app in Django (a blog) and I wanted to add a date field. I read in the documentation that the way to go was using `models.DateTimeField()`. Since I already had populate the database I added the `null=True` option. So in my models.py it was like this:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(null=True,auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, editable=True)
```

I migrate it and it was okey. I went to the admin page and changed the date values for the existing tuples. Then I went to my models.py file and altered the date field:

```
date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False,default=models.DateTimeField())
```

I added the default because when I was running makemigrations, a prompt would show up saying I had to put a default value or add a `null=True` and my noob head though that what I did made sense. When I ran makemigrations I got no errors but when I tried to actually migrate *this* appeared:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blogApp, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying blogApp.0007_auto_20200808_0006...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 231, in handle
    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 249, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.alter_field(from_model, from_field, to_field)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 138, in alter_field
    super().alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, strict=strict)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 566, in alter_field
    self._alter_field(model, old_field, new_field, old_type, new_type,
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 360, in _alter_field
    self._remake_table(model, alter_field=(old_field, new_field))
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 200, in _remake_table
    'default': self.quote_value(self.effective_default(new_field))
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 303, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 821, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1376, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1355, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1215, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1316, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/home/min/Documentos/Programação/Python/myDjangoBlog/VirtualEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 107, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

So I tried just excluding the date field from the model but the same error message persist wherever I try to migrate. I tried altering the field to how it was in the first migrate but still same error.
I don't wanna drop my database now but I don't know why this message persist even when I erase any trace of a `DateTimeField()` object from my model. I looked up how to exclude mgrations and only found people wanting to erase their whole database. I don't want that, maybe just excluding the pending migrations could work but I don't know how and I can't seem to find an asnwer for my especific problem.

Currently my project is like this:
Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    tag_names = [
        ("Tech","Tech"),
        ("Music","Music"),
        ("Art","Art"),
        ("Miscellaneous","Miscellaneous")]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=tag_names, default="Miscellaneous")
    #date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title+' | '+str(self.author)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView  
from .models import Post

# def home(request):
#     return render(request,"home.html", {})

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

class PostView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_details.html'
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
#from . import views
from .views import HomeView, PostView

urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.home,name="home"),
    path('post/<int:pk>',PostView.as_view(),name="posts"),
    path('', HomeView.as_view(),name="home")
]
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for core project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '(#ra)3hh^=z^q-&ixp7p-3m%@8!$*)-5#$rf^$+v_%ucis1gb2'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blogApp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

btw my app name is blogApp.

Comment: If the broken migration has never been successfully applied you can delete the broken migration file

Comment: I think you added the default date like 2019-12-31 while it should be '2019-12-31.'. You can delete that specific migration files and try again or you can edit that migrations file. located at yourapp/migrations folder.